# Add vertical space in equations

Tags: equations, text

i have a series of equalities in an equation so i want to start a new line. I've seen the use of `\begin{align*}` but i want to work inside an equation. For example :

```
\begin{equation}
a+b=c+d=d+e
\end{equation}
```

I want to have :

```
a+b=
c+d=
d+e
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!  I cannot understand well what you want to achieve: should the three equation be aligned along the “=” sign?  Should they be horizontally centered independently from one another?  Please clarify.

Comment: And what's wrong with `\begin{align} a+b &= \notag\\ c+d&= \notag\\ d+e & \end{align}`?

Comment: Another thing that is not clear is why the title of your question is about “vertical space”, whilst the question itself doesn’t mention vertical spacing at all.  If what you want is to split the equation into several lines, while retaining a single equation number, you can use the `split` environment inside an `equation`.

Comment: @marmot i want to use `equation` because i need to recall it

Comment: @GuM Thank you, yes my question is not fully clear but i think the answer of werner is what i want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use line-breaks inside an `equation`, unless you provide a stackable environment, like `array`. However, you're better off using [`amsmath`](//ctan.org/pkg/amsmath)'s `align`-like functionality:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \begin{array}{l}
    a + b = {} \\
    c + d = {} \\
    d + e
  \end{array}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
  \begin{aligned}
       & a + b \\
    ={}& c + d \\
    ={}& d + e
  \end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```